# Recursive Ajax Call not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to make back to back ajax get call, using $.ajax jquery method(Since my JSON data is around 2MB), it works fine in Chrome but IE11 doesn't seems to understand.In IE11, it falls on fail method of ajax, in one of the recursive call & after that it moves out of recursion. I debugged & hover over responseText in fail event, it gives me string(one of the object of long json) with backslashes

> [{\"row_index\":\"401\",\"value\":\"Greece\",\"system\":true,\"global\":true}]

However, it works fine in chrome, Even in network monitor IE11, it shows no backslash responses. In IE11 console, it shows string without backslashes

```
var myArray =[];
function recursiveAjax(j){
    //where requestIds is like ["2","5", "1"] (list of ids) 
   $.ajax({url:myURL + JSON.stringify(requestIds) + "&point1="+range[j].start+"&point2="+range[j].end +"&cacheUniq=" + (new Date()).getTime(), dataType: "json", type:'Get', cache:false, success: function (data) {

   myArray.push(data)
   if(j < range.length-1 )// Where range is populated array of object
            {
                j++;
                recursiveAjax(j);
                //setTimeout(recursiveAjax(j),500*j);

            }   
   });
   })

   }
recursiveAjax(0)
```

Comment: What does _doesn't seems to understand_ mean? Does it throw any errors, what does the console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a special character in my json data, which was causing error event to trigger in IE11 only

> �